# Express sum of complex exponentials as 1 + sum of cosines

Tags: exponential-sum

I'm told that I can express the following sum of complex exponentials:

$$\sum_{n=0}^6 e^{-j\Omega n}$$

As 1 plus 3 cosine terms.  I'm having a really hard time arriving at this, I see where the 1 comes from, when n = 0 and I consider:

$$e^{-j\theta}=cos(\theta) - jsin(\theta)$$

But I feel as though I'm missing something, and I'm failing to arrive at just 3 other cosine terms.  Is it possible somebody can point me in the right direction?  This problem originates from a class I am taking in digital signal processing.

Any help would be humbly and greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only true if you factor out $e^{-j\Omega 3}$. Then you obtain
$$\sum_{n=0}^6 e^{-j\Omega n} = e^{-j\Omega 3} \left(e^{j\Omega 3} + e^{j\Omega 2} + e^{j\Omega} + 1 + e^{-j\Omega} + e^{-j\Omega 2}+e^{-j\Omega 3} \right).$$
To evaluate this, you can use that
$$2 \cos(x) = e^{x} + e^{-x}.$$

Comment: I understand, thank you!